# Dropping curly brackets from a list

Tags: plotting, manipulate, head

I would like to make many plots using the same plot parameters.  I am trying to define a plot parameter list such as

```
plotparams={PlotRange->{0,1}, PlotPadding->0, Axes->False, GridLines->Automatic, Frame->True};
```

Then use ListPlot and incorporate the plotparams

```
ListPlot[{{0,0},{0.1,0.1},{0.2,0.2}},plotparams]
```

This gives an error since plotparams is a list and ListPlot is not expecting a list at that point.  Is there a method for simply stripping the head of the list and efficiently feeding ListPlot the desired rules?

Comment: The error says that PlotPadding is not a legal option for ListPlot. Remove this and you get your plot. You can tell that it is not an option since it is highlighted in blue.

Comment: Yes, there is a method for that (see `Splice` or `Sequence`) but this is not the issue in your case as @bills pointed out.

Comment: The option is `PlotRangePadding`; however, if you set it to `0`, two of your points are barely visible. You could also use `lp = ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.02, Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True] &; lp@{{0, 0}, {0.1, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.2}}`

Answer (score 2):

First you need to correct your list of options so that all the options are valid,

```
plotparams =
  {PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Axes -> False, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True};
```

Then you need to use `Sequence` to splice the options into the `ListPlot` expression.

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {0.1, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.2}}, Sequence @@ plotparams]
```

[image: plot]

Note: you can not use `Splice` in this situation. It only works for expressions with head `List` and your expression has head `ListPlot`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, though, it's not even necessary to use `Sequence @@`. You can pass options as a list just fine.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit. You're right, but the OP specifically asked about dropping the list braces, i.e., the head `List`.